# Rails relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I define a relationship where an employee has a manager, and potentially some subordinates (all of which would be examples of the Employee model)? My attempt so far results in any given person only having a maximum of one subordinate.

```
has_one :manager, :class_name => Employee, :foreign_key => "manager"
has_many :subordinates, :class_name => Employee, :foreign_key => "manager"
```

I feel like this one's obvious, but all the banging of my head against the wall is making it difficult.

Comment: You should use `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
class Employee

  belongs_to :manager,      :class_name => 'Employee', :inverse_of => :subordinates
  has_many   :subordinates, :class_name => 'Employee', :inverse_of => :manager

end
```